# iPhoneアプリ申請時、XcodeでArchive後のValidateボタンが押せない

Tags: xcode

iPhoneアプリ申請の為,Xcodeのアップロード用バイナリを作成するにあたり

1. Generic IOS Deviceを選択
2. Product -> Archive
3. ビルドが実行されArchiveが表示
4. SuccessしArchiveは表示されるのだがValidateボタンがグレー表示
   で押せません。

DetailsにはVersion,Identifier,Typeは表示されています。

※ エラー表示が見当たらないので,これだけの情報では漠然としていますが確認する場所があれば教えて戴けないでしょうか？
(Bundle Identifier,Provisioning Profileは問題ないと自分では思っていますが,次に進める為)

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/106762

Comment: dokubeko さんと tamatw2020 さんの会話をチャットに移動しました。詳細情報をお探しの方はこちらをご覧ください： http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70926/discussion-on-question-by-tamatw2020-iphonexcodearchivevalidate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 「Upload to App Store...」「Validate...」「Export...」などのボタンがグレーアウトしている

[Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/jp/) に参加していない（いわゆる無料の）アカウントではそうなるようです。Apple Developer Program に参加しているアカウントを Xcode に追加し、そのアカウントを指定してアプリのアーカイブを作成してください。